# change array output with changing value

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a table with a value `$i` for a column that simply counts/labels each row (goes from 1 to 12).

I have an array that I would like to add, into another table column. What I am trying to do, is have the array change the value it is outputting each time the `$i` value changes.

This is sort of what it looks like as for coding:

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    $myarray= array('one', 'two', 'three', 'etc...')
?>
<center>
<?php
    echo'<table width="100%">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th></th>';
    echo '<th>Country</th>';
    echo '<th>Greeting</th>';
    echo '<th>Translation</th>';
    echo '<th>Language</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $number_of_rows = 11;

    for ($row = 0; $row <= $number_of_rows; $row++) {
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td >'. $i++ . '</td>';
            echo '<td >'. “Blue” . '</td>';
            echo '<td >'. “Red” . '</td>';
            echo '<td >'. “Green” . '</td>';
            echo '<td >'. “Black” . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
?>
</center>
```

I'm quite new to php, so it's a bit confusing to me. Sorry for any mistakes.

This is where I'm a bit stuck. I want the row that says "Green" to be the row that I am going to implement my array. Each row it will say something different, as the $i value is different for each row. However, I'm not quite sure how to implement this with the current set up that I have going? Is there a way I can do it? Or do I have to take a different route?

Comment: sorry I should try to explain more. There will be 11 rows total. Each of the rows will have td's with the data, green, blue, red, etc. I want the td's with the data green, to have my array in it. To answer your question, yes. I want each of the rows to display a different element of my array.

Comment: This is not a clear [mcve].